# Существуют ли сервисы удаленного доступа к APPLE OS X системе?

Tags: macos, хостинг, apple, доступ, сервисы

Существуют ли сервисы удаленного доступа к APPLE OS X системе?

Т.е. я заплатил деньги за доступ к удаленной APPLE OS X системе и через какую-нибудь программу удаленного администрирования пользуюсь системой?

Comment: VNC http://ru.wikihow.com/установить-VNC-на-Mac-OS-X

Comment: Почитайте внимательно что я написал, о программах удаленного доступа я не спрашивал, у меня нет Mac'а, потому я спросил про возможность за деньжку через удаленный рабочий стол поюзать Mac OS ( OS X)

Comment: Mac OS хостинг типа, уже подсказали мне в другом месте...

Comment: Так в чем проблема, установи MAC себе на комп или виртуалку, не буду учить как, установи на ней VNC сервер, на компе VNC клиент и вуаля... Для каких задач это все нужно?

Comment: У меня старый древний ноутбук на пне, с 2 Гб оперативки и естественно без поддержки аппаратной виртуализации. Прежде чем писать тут я конечно же пытался замутить хакинтош или запустить виртуалку на ноуте - но все попытки не принесли результата. Потому решил пойти другим путем.

Comment: Лучший вариант - купить хардварный мак

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да существуют такие сервисы  [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/),[xcloud](https://xcloud.me/)  и [hostmyapple](http://www.hostmyapple.com/macvps.html)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/149426)

Comment: @tCode: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/199934 . Спасибо.

Comment: Alex.B: вместо «вот» лучше указать названия сервисов. Чтобы, если сервисы сменят URL, их легче было бы нагуглить по названиям. Спасибо.

Comment: поправил, спасибо за уточнение.